# How to recursively list the dimensions of all images in a folder recursively using Shell script?

Tags: image, shell, recursion, terminal, dimensions

I think the title should explain clearly what I'm trying to do. I'm very new to shell scripts and have managed to put some code together but it isn't right at all- every file on my computer is being listed

I would also ideally like to check all image types ( at least jpg, png and gif)

```
find "$1" -name ".jpg" | while read imagePath ; do
imageFile=$(basename "$imagePath")
dimensions=$(sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth * )
echo "$videoFile: $dimensions" done
```

Can anyone help?
Thankyou!

Comment: What error do you get?  You don't use imageFile, which is good because the call to basename is unnecessary, and you are missing a `;` before `done`.  Otherwise, it looks fine syntactically.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply William, I'm not getting an error, I need to filter out non image files. Will update my question, sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work nicely for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.gif" \) -print0 | \
   while read -d $'\0' -r image; do
      read w h < <(sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight "$image" | \
         awk '/Width:/{w=$2} /Height:/{h=$2} END{print w " " h}')
      echo $image $w $h 
   done
```

**Sample Output**

```
./start2.png 640 480
./step2.gif 1 3918
./step2.jpg 1 3918
./step3.gif 2551 1
./survey.gif 2651 4018
./t.jpg 1 463
./tiger.png 258 296
```

Save the above in a file called `pics`, then go to the Terminal and type the following one time to make it executable:

```
chmod +x pics
```

Then, when you want to run it, just type:

```
./pics
```

Though, personally, I would prefer ImageMagick over `SIPS`, since you can do something similar in one line:

```
identify -format "%f: %wx%h\n" *.jpg *.gif *.png
```

**Sample Output**:

```
7T6Dj.jpg: 1920x1080
a.jpg: 400x463
b.jpg: 400x463
back.jpg: 906x603
background.jpg: 906x603
```

If you think of installing ImageMagick on a Mac - use `homebrew` and it is easy.

**Updated Answer**

If you only want to output each image size once, ignoring second and subsequent images with identical dimensions, you can add some `awk` at the end like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find all types of imagery GIF, JPG, PNG
find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.gif" \) -print0 | \
   while read -d $'\0' -r image; do
      read w h < <(sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight "$image" | \
         awk '/Width:/{w=$2} /Height:/{h=$2} END{print w " " h}')
      echo $image $w $h 
   done | awk '{w=$(NF-1); h=$(NF); if(!seen[w SUBSEP h]++)print $0}'
```

Comment: Hi, this is great though I'm getting an error, looks like a typo: image_dimensions.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
 Also - to be clear I'm running the script by typing sh imagedimensions.sh /path/to/FolderOfImages

Comment: No, it's `bash`. Save in a file called `pics` or some such, then in the terminal, type `chmod +x pics` just once to make it executable, then do this to run it: `./pics`

Comment: Works great! Many thanks. One further question - how could I only echo each time there is an image with dimensions that haven't previously been listed?

Comment: Not sure I understand. It will only do each image you have once so it won't list any file more than once.

Comment: I had a try at what I think you mean - please take a look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Hi Mark, that is exactly what I meant, this has saved me such a long time. I am very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find `sips` so based on the answer above, this one-liner works for me:

```
$ identify -format "%f: %wx%h\n" *.jpg *.gif *.png | cut -d: -f2 | sort -u | sed 's/x/\t/g'
```

This outputs a width, height tab-delimited list of filesizes in the current directory (I'm trying to see how many different sizes of images I have in my directory)

```
 909    503
 924    503
```

**notes**

Example output, first part:

```
jobs8.png: 909x503
jobs.png: 909x503
lobstr.png: 924x503
```

Second part, cut out filename:

```
 909x503
 909x503
 924x503
```

Remove duplicates:

```
 909x503
 924x503
```

Make pretty with tabs:

```
 909    503
 924    503
```

Comment: `sips` is a binary included with Mac OS, so if you're not on a Mac I don't believe you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **ImageMagick** installed, you could combine its "**identify**" command with "**find**".

The following oneliner will give you a recursive list of all jpg images in the underlying directories:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec identify {} \;
```